# Python - Best method to create list made of variables

Tags: python, list

I made this chunk of code but I think this isn't the "best" out there... how can I create a list made of other variables?

```
track_data = []
track_data.append(track['title'][0])
track_data.append(track['artist'][0])
track_data.append(track['album'][0])
return track_data
```

I tried to to do

```
track_data = [track['title'][0], track['artist'][0], track['album'][0]]
```

but it didn't appear as a good solution for my IDE (PyCharm).

What should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I do when I want to remember the Awesomeness of Python

```
track_data = [track[prop][0] for prop in ('title', 'artist', 'album')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fields = ['title', 'artist', 'album']
track_data = [track[f][0] for f in fields]
```